# The index of a JS object returns all values in object rather than the actual index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Let me explain this really quickly, when I fetch data from the database, there's a parent object and inside there is an array of objects, what I'm looking to achieve is to write the correct path so I can access specific items in the db.

When receiving the data I store two variables like so:

```
for (let a in obj) {
    list.push(obj[a]);
    keys.push(a);
}
this.setState({
    list: list,
    keys: keys,
});
```

Executing this code will print the following:

```
console.log(this.state.keys[index]);
```

> HZlgUZ21vKbungnxaxDJXrTUr2z1

This always returns the exact parent object `id`

But the issue is that I cannot access the index of the nested items:

```
console.log(this.state.list[index]);
```

> Object {-LORYsI9mLP8mu_2BTKS: Object, -LORZVOq8SMUgTOPgpXK: Object,
>   -LORZtqZeg3nyOW4p9I1: Object, -LOYbElg81jbPtao2nl4: Object}

What I'm looking for is that nested item ID not all the values

i attached a picture of the database so you can see how it looks like

[image]

Here's a minimal representation of the view:

```
const listItems = this.state.list.map((item, index) =>
        Object.values(item).map(nestedItem => (
<div>
  {nestedItem.title}
  <button
   onClick={() => this.update(index)}
   >
  CLICK
  </button>
</div>
  ))
);
```

It's pretty easy to solve it's just that I am still learning main concepts of programming but this nested objects always makes me frustrated. Please someone come to my rescue

Comment: when you're looking into the object do you have a specific key you're looking for ? It's simple enough to look into an object, but you need to know what you're looking for or be okay with getting everything.

Comment: @zfrisch in the example provided I am trying to do `this.state.list[index][3] ` but generated dynamically, is that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to apply the below concept in your example?

Consider you have a JSON structure like

```
var obj = {
        a: {
             blue:16,
             green:30,
             red:39
           },
        b: {
             orange:56,
             yellow:34,
             white:35    
           },
        c: {
             black:3,
             brown:43,
             purple:12  
            }
        };
```

Now, when you run a `for...in` loop over this object

```
for (let key in obj) {
   list.push(obj[key]); 
   keys.push(a);
}
```

`obj[key]` will return the value `{blue:16,green:30,red:39}` which ultimately is pushed into the list array

If you want the values blue, green and red, you can do something like

```
Object.keys(obj[key]); //will return an array ['blue', 'green', 'red']
```

Comment: Appreciate your help but I have more complex issue, I still couldn't figure this out, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765825/how-to-access-index-of-nested-items-in-js-object