# How to print property name rather than the whole JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Let's suppose :

```
this.state.keys[index] =
    Object { -ID01: Object, -ID02: Object, -ID03: Object, -IDO4: Object }
```

How to print`-ID02` for example ? I am looking for the propriety name`-ID02` not what's inside and its actual values

```
// Expected Output  -ID02 (string)
```

Comment: What's with the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763824/the-index-of-a-js-object-returns-all-values-in-object-rather-than-the-actual-ind)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could `Object.keys()` and index into the key of interest. For e.g. `-ID02` would be at index `1`. Therefore, `Object.keys(this.state.keys)[1]` would give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(this.state.keys[index])
```

will give you the keys in that object as an array.

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object `obj`, then `Object.keys(obj)` will return an array of all the keys in that object. For eg:

```
const obj = { '-ID01': Object, '-ID02': Object, '-ID03': Object, '-IDO4': Object };
let keys = Object.keys(obj); //['-ID01', '-ID02', '-ID03', '-ID04']
```