# How to access index of nested items in JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This is where I should probably add something to fix the issue, I am stuck with this index that returns the whole object, my goal is to print the index of clicked item, please someone help

```
 const listItems = this.state.list.map((item, index) =>
        Object.values(item).map(nestedItem => (
        <div>
            <Card.Header>
                {nestedItem.title}
            </Card.Header>
            <div class="ui buttons fluid">
            <button
                onClick={() => this.upvote(index)}
            >
                UPVOTE
            </button>
        </div>
        ))
    );
```

The code below is working correctly it's just that I hard coded the index I am looking for `2` in this example

```
console.log(Object.keys(this.state.list[index])[2]);
```

And this is the whole object, all I need now is the index of it

```
0: "-LORYsI9mLP8mu_2BTKS"
1: "-LORZVOq8SMUgTOPgpXK"
2: "-LORZtqZeg3nyOW4p9I1"
3: "-LOYbElg81jbPtao2nl4"
4: "-LOZ3pNNMAOtNxMWNDi4"
```

Comment: I can't understand what do you want to achieve. Could you provide some input data example and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need the index of the inner mapping? I'm confused by the question still, but perhaps something like this.

```
const listItems = this.state.list.map((item, index) =>
        Object.values(item).map((nestedItem, nestedIndex) => (
        <div>
            <Card.Header>
                {nestedItem.title}
            </Card.Header>
            <div class="ui buttons fluid">
            <button
                onClick={() => this.upvote(index, nestedIndex)}
            >
                UPVOTE
            </button>
        </div>
        ))
    );
```

If this doesn't work, could you post an example of your data structure?

here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax

Comment: This is actually a great suggestion, Object.keys(this.state.list[nestedIndex])[index] Thanks so much @nick-brady

Answer (score 0):

If you want the indices for the nested items, the you'll need to have another variable in the map fn

`Object.values(item).map((nestedItem, nestedIndex) => <div>...</div>`

and then use the `nestedIndex` variable in your `upvote` method